# I have troubles with proving the induction step: $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{3}{4} * \frac{5}{6} * ... * \frac{(2k+1)}{2k+2} ≤ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+3}}$

Tags: inequality, induction

Let's assume that the unequality is right if $n = k$, that is:

> $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{3}{4} * \frac{5}{6} * ... * \frac{(2k-1)}{2k}  ≤  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}}$

Let's prove that the unequality is right for $n = k + 1$ as well, that is:

> $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{3}{4} * \frac{5}{6} * ... * \frac{(2k+1)}{2k+2}  ≤  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+3}}$

I've spent a comparable amount of time trying to prove this point but looks like I can't grasp what to do.

Comment: Have you tried using the induction hypothesis to simplify the inequality?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing i did

Comment: The product is even smaller. We have  $\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2k+1}{2k+2} \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi (n +\frac{5}{4})} }\tag{*}$ Notice that because $\frac{5}{4} \gt 3$ inequality $(*)$ is sharper than that with $\pi n + 3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that$$\frac12\times\frac34\times\frac56\times\cdots\times\frac{2k-1}{2k}\times\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt{2k+1}}\times\frac{2k+1}{2k+2},$$by the induction hypothesis. So, it would be great if you could prove that$$\frac1{\sqrt{2k+1}}\times\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt{2k+3}}\tag1$$But $(1)$ is equivalent to$$\left(\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}\right)^2\leqslant\frac{2k+1}{2k+3},$$which in turn is equivalent to$$(2k+1)(2k+3)\leqslant(2k+2)^2.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: understood, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $$\frac{a}{b}<1 \Rightarrow \frac{a}{b} < \frac{a+x}{b+x}, x>0.~~~(1)$$
Let  $$P_1=\frac{1}{2}~ \frac{3}{4}~ \frac{5}{6}....\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}.$$
Let us add 1, up and down in each fraction to get
$$P_2=\frac{2}{3} ~\frac{4}{5} ~\frac{6}{7}...\frac{2k+2}{2k+3}.$$
So By (1), $$P_1<P_2 \Rightarrow P_1^2 < P_1. P_2 \Rightarrow P_1^2 < \frac{1}{2k+3}$$$$\Rightarrow P_1 <\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+3}}.$$

Comment: +1 Extremely insightful. Saw the same technique once in a Singapore Olympiad book.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the induction hypotesis reduces to show that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}} \frac{(2k+1)}{2k+2}  ≤  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+3}} \implies\sqrt{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\le 2k+2$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using the induction hypothesis:

$$\frac{2k+1}{2k+2} ≤ \frac{\sqrt{2k+1}}{\sqrt{2k+3}}$$

Now let $u = 2k+2$:

$$\frac{u-1}{u} ≤ \frac{\sqrt{u-1}}{\sqrt{u+1}}$$

For $u ≥ 1$ or $2k + 2 ≥ 1$ which implies $k ≥ -\frac{1}{2}$, both sides are positive. So we can square both sides:

$$\frac{u^2-2u+1}{u^2} ≤ \frac{u-1}{u+1}$$
$$u^3-u^2-u+1 ≤ u^3-u^2$$
$$u ≥ 1$$

Obviously this is not a formal proof. To do so, you need to invert all the steps starting from $u ≥ 1$.